# How ‘this’ work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript I need some help to understand how **this** keyword works in JavaScript. When I run the following code it result 2 which is obvious.

```
function foo() {
  console.log( this.a );
}

var obj = {
  a: 2,
  foo: foo
};

var a = 'global a';

obj.foo(); // 2
```

but if I run the following code then wthen print global a instead of obj.a.

```
function foo(){
  console.log(this.a);
}

var obj = {
  a:2,
  foo:foo
}

var bar = obj.foo;
var a = 'global a';

bar();
```

please anyone tell me  why this print global a?

Comment: You need to always use write `"use strict";` at the top of your files. Do not target sloppy mode period.

Comment: Assuming `window` is the global scope, does it become more obvious if you compare `window.obj.foo(); // 2` with `window.bar(); // 'global a'`?

Comment: Is there default binding applies?  because  bar() is plain and undercoated call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you first example, when you call the function `foo` on the variable `obj`, the context of `this` is the `obj` itself. That's why `a == 2`. Now, when you reference the function `foo` to the variable `bar`, the context of `this` is the global `window`, and the variable `a` in this context is `global a`. In this case, to make the function `foo` behave the same way as in the first example, you can bind it to the `obj` context. Like this:

```js
function foo(){
  console.log(this.a);
}

var obj = {
  a:2,
  foo:foo
}

// bind the context to obj
var bar = obj.foo.bind(obj);
var a = 'global a';

bar();
```

I hope I could make myself clear... ;)

Comment: thanks @juliobetta 
now i understand how this works in this code...

Answer (score -1):

On the first code obj has its own `a` variable and `foo()` function is called on `obj`. 
On your second example you are only giving bar a reference to the function so when it is called it prints the member variable of the class, in this case `a = global a`